# Web part loading very slow in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, asp.net-3.5

I have a sharepoint site in which I have deployed 10 different custom web parts. There I have a particular web part which takes lots of time to load. (This particular web part is kind of a blog aggregator which connects to rss' and show the most recent blog post of each of the blogs specified in a list). All my other web parts are pretty much basic web parts. Since my blog aggregator web part takes a lot of time, it takes a considerable time to load the sharepoint site. So, my problem is that, how to load my sharepoint site with other web parts instantly, while loading the blog aggregator in background? (Just like in out-of-the-box RSS aggregator in sharepoint)

Your help is highly appreciable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the errant web part is closed source or vendor supplied, there's not much you can do (other than begging them to release an update).

If you can update the web part, one of the things that has worked for me is to split the web part's logic between javascript and a web service, and invoke the web service asynchronously via javascript. This will make the page appear to load faster because the rest of the page can render while your RSS part is waiting for a response. You will need to use a web service, rather than downloading the RSS content directly via javascript, to get around cross-site scripting protection in most browsers.

A javascript library like jquery makes it fairly simple to [asynchronously invoke a web service](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/jQuery/310_Calling_a_WebService_using_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx).

The downside of this approach is that you'll probably need to tear out the guts of your web part and start over.